# X11 / DBUS messaging from Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, x11, dbus

Is it possible to do X11 and/or DBUS messaging from a Chrome Extension?

I would like to communicate to [Skype API](http://developer.skype.com/public-api-reference#Linux) on a Linux machine and it supports either DBUS or X11.

Answer (score 3):

I found in progress plugin for Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/npapi-dbus/